# dumb Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using Sql server 2012, Entity Framework 5.0

Table Customer: Id ...
                NickName (nvarchar(100)) Is Nullable

```
Customer ICustomer service:    Customer GetCustomer(Func<Customer, bool> pre);


public Customer GetCustomer(Func<Customer, bool> pre)
        {
            return _customerRepository.Table.Where(pre).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

When i try to get the data:

```
  var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer(c => c.Nickname.Equals("abc"));
```

It generates an error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

when NickName has NULL data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct you can't call a method against null... Think of it this way:

When a variable is null you are trying to do the following:
null.Method() <- this is bad..

what you may want to try is

```
var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer(c => "abc".Equals(c.Nickname));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `==`

```
var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer(c => c.Nickname == "abc");
```

Or just checking for null:

```
var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer(c => c.Nickname != null && c.Nickname.Equals("abc"));
```

Comment: The first example will get converted to SQL that will obey the database defaults for null comparisons and collation, and is easy to read (default will be to only match records where Nickname is not null and matches "abc" without caring about case for Latin1_General_CI_AS).